# React api property error everytime page is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I am new to React and I am fetching the data from covid api and the first render there is no error in the page but refresh the page and I get an error. I have used useEffect hoook and passed an empty array as the parameter.

```
useEffect(()=>{

  axios.all([
    axios.get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/all?lastdays=all'),

    axios.get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/continents'),
    
  ])
.then(function(response) {
    setCovid(response[0].data);
    setContinent(response[1].data);
    
  
  }).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
},[])
```

the states i have defined are:

```
const [covid,setCovid]=useState([]);
const [continent,setContinent]=useState([]);
```

The data fetched for `axios.get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/continents')` is of the form

```
[
  {
    "updated": 1607090269045,
    "cases": 16896655,
    "todayCases": 16922,
    "deaths": 420577,
    "todayDeaths": 718,
    "recovered": 10332765,
    "todayRecovered": 12336,
    "active": 6143313,
    "critical": 30951,
    "casesPerOneMillion": 28586.82,
    "deathsPerOneMillion": 711.56,
    "tests": 221877339,
    "testsPerOneMillion": 375386.05,
    "population": 591064426,
    "continent": "North America",
    "activePerOneMillion": 10393.64,
    "recoveredPerOneMillion": 17481.62,
    "criticalPerOneMillion": 52.36,
    "continentInfo": {
      "lat": 31.6768272,
      "long": -146.4707474
    },
    "countries": [
...
```

where continent is one of the values.

And outside the useEffect I have declared

```
console.log(continent[0].continent);
```

For the first render, it works fine, but when I refresh the page, I get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'continent' of undefined
```

Also, for the first render even though I have passed empty array as the parameter in the useEffect, the console displays 6 outputs, how do i make it just one render?

Kindly help me rectify these two errors, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

don't console log outside `useFfect`, it will give you an error for sure. because Axios takes time to resolve requests and returns data, within that time the value of  `continent` state will remain `[]` and that is why that error.

Instead, console log after the Axios returns the result inside then block

```
useEffect(()=>{

  axios.all([
    axios.get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/all?lastdays=all'),

    axios.get('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/continents'),
    
  ])
.then(function(response) {
    setCovid(response[0].data);
    setContinent(response[1].data);
    console.log(continent[0].continent);
  }).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
},[])
```

and in the future, if you want to avoid that error then just to be on the safer side use null propagation operator like shown below:

```
console.log(continent[0]?.continent);
```